# Why does calling a method generate a CS0019 error?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm practicing C# by making a simple program that outputs some messages in the console whenever I click, in Unity.

The theme is a die rolling. When I click, it will simulate a roll using Random.Range();. If rolling a 6 it outputs a message to the console, otherwise it would just tell you your result through to the console.

I got the error code CS0019.

[image: the error from the Unity console]

My code:

```
    void Start () {

        rollingDice ();
    }

    //This Function handles the rolling of the die. When called, it will generate a random number from; Random.Range between the number of 1 to 6, just like a die.
    int rollingDice ()
    {
        int Dice = Random.Range (0,6);
        return Dice;
    }
//This Function executes the Function rollingDice (); upon click
    void OnMouseDown()
    {
        rollingDice ();
    }


    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () 
    {       
        if (rollingDice == 6) {               //I've put the if statements here in update to check whether I've 
                                                               //rolled a 6 or not every frame.
            Debug.Log ("You've hit the highest number!!");
        } else {
            Debug.Log ("Your last roll was: " + rollingDice);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in *Pikoh's* [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47114783/3785314), you need to add `()` in front of a function name to call it.

---

This is only solves your compilation problem. There are many issues not discussed that I decided to leave this answer.

**1**.Each time you do `if (rollingDice() == 6)`  you will get a new random number. When you do `Debug.Log ("Your last roll was: " + rollingDice());`, you will get another new random number.

The random numbers from  `if (rollingDice() == 6)`, the `OnMouseDown()` function  and `Debug.Log("Your last roll was: " + rollingDice());` will not be the-same.

**2**.Unity's [`Random.Range`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47114783/3785314) second parameter is exclusive which means that Unity does not include it. It includes max-1.

If you want to generate random number between `0` and `6`, you have to pass `7` to the second parameter. That should be `Random.Range(0, 7)`.

**With your current code,  `if (rolledDice == 6)` will never be true.**

Also, dice number is between `1` and `6` **not** `0` and `6` so `Random.Range(1, 7)` should be used.

---

You have to call `rollingDice()` once then store it in a temporary variable and re-use it.

```
int rolledDice = -1;

void Start()
{
    rolledDice = rollingDice();
}

//This Function handles the rolling of the die. When called, it will generate a random number from; Random.Range between the number of 1 to 6, just like a die.
int rollingDice()
{
    int Dice = UnityEngine.Random.Range(1, 7);
    return Dice;
}

//This Function executes the Function rollingDice (); upon click
void OnMouseDown()
{
    rolledDice = rollingDice();
}


// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    if (rolledDice == 6)
    {               //I've put the if statements here in update to check whether I've 
                    //rolled a 6 or not every frame.
        Debug.Log("You've hit the highest number!!");
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.Log("Your last roll was: " + rolledDice);
    }

}
```

---

Finally, note that `OnMouseDown()` is used to detect mouse click on an Object. You didn't mention this. You simply said you want to generate random number when mouse is clicked not when mouse is clicked on a GameObject. The `Input.GetMouseButtonDown` function is used to detect mouse click so your actual code should look like something below:

```
int rolledDice = -1;

void Start()
{
    rolledDice = rollingDice();
}

//This Function handles the rolling of the die. When called, it will generate a random number from; Random.Range between the number of 1 to 6, just like a die.
int rollingDice()
{
    int Dice = UnityEngine.Random.Range(1, 7);
    return Dice;
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
    {
        rolledDice = rollingDice();

        if (rolledDice == 6)
        {               //I've put the if statements here in update to check whether I've 
                        //rolled a 6 or not every frame.
            Debug.Log("You've hit the highest number!!");
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log("Your last roll was: " + rolledDice);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Excellent answer. I just stopped in the compilation error,but i'm sure your answer would help OP a lot.

Comment: Thanks. I was about to move on but I realized that OP will have many issues even after fixing the compilation problem. Just so many issues.

Comment: @Programmer. This is pretty great! I'm just milling over the code to learn what every aspect of it would do, and I have a few questions on just how/why things are written there.

1. So, you've made a temporary variable to store the current roll and I see that it's value is '-1', why is that?

2. Also we call it in Start, why does it equal rollingDice()?

3. And why does (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)). Have a 0, in it's parenthesis?

Thanks, I was just curious, and cheers for correcting my code.

Comment: **1.** `-1` is there so that you can use `-1` to check if the dice has been rolled or not. `-1` is the default value. You can make it any value as long as it's not a value between 1 and 6. **2.** It does not equal `rollindDice()`. I am simply generating a random number by calling the `rollingDice()` function and assigning the value to the temporary variable `rolledDice`. That part is not necessary since I am doing it in the `Update` function. I only did it to remove the default `-1` value. **3.** 0 is for the left mouse button. 1 is for right mouse button and 2 is for the middle mouse button.

Answer (score 1):

When calling a method,you need to add parethesis after its name. So:

```
if (rollingDice == 6)
```

Should be:

```
if (rollingDice() == 6)
```

And

```
Debug.Log ("Your last roll was: " + rollingDice);
```

Should be

```
Debug.Log ("Your last roll was: " + rollingDice());
```

Btw,i guess it must be a typo,but just in case it's a common convention that the parenthesis are next to the method name,so delete the space you have in some cases. For example:

```
void Start () 
{ 
   rollingDice (); 
}
```

Should be:

```
void Start() 
{ 
   rollingDice(); 
}
```

Comment: there is a close-vote reason for typos. and also `methodName ()` with space works just fine, not "parenthesis must always be next to the method name". there is even formatting options in Visual Studio to force spaces

Comment: You are right @ASh, the space does not affect but i think it's a common convention in c# to put parenthesis next to the method name. And i didn't thought about closing the question based on typo, as the OP is a newbie and obviously doesn't know that parenthesis are needed when calling methods. But you may be right, thank you for pointing it out.

Comment: Oh man, now it works. I didn't know that about when **calling** a method you had to put the parenthesis, cheers for that. As for the spacing Monodevelop automatically spaces for me, I just checked. I personally like it not having any spaces. Thanks again @Pikoh.

Comment: You're welcome. You should accept one answer,mine or @Programmer. Maybe his, is more complete :)